# LISP - Divide a list with the first element of that list

Tags: common-lisp

I want to write a recursive function that takes a list and then divides that list with the first element. When I call the function with

```
(divfirst '(3 6 9 12))
```

It should return

```
(1 2 3 4)
```

So far I got this

```
(defun divfirst (list)
  (COND ((= (FIRST list) 0) (PRINT 'div_durch_null)) ; Catch division by 0
        (list (/ (FIRST(REST list)) (FIRST list)) (divfirst (cons (FIRST L) (REST L)))) ; Division and recursion
  )
)
```

However, as it is right now it crashes the Lisp debugger when I try to call it and it's also not doing what it's supposed to which is dividing the first element by itself too. If anyone got a hint how I should construct the division and recursion I'll gladly take it.

Comment: `(mapcar (lambda (elem) (/ elem (first list))) (rest list))`.  Division by zero can be caught as a condition, or tested for around this.

Comment: @Kaz , I want to do it recursively, not with mapcar.

Comment: Sure thing! `(defun recursive-mapcar (fun list) (if list (cons (funcall fun (car list)) (recursive-mapcar fun (cdr list)))))`.  However, I wouldn't do this in production code; I'd use the built-in `mapcar`.

Comment: Unfortunately your code is mostly unreadable, since it is not formatted in a readable way. Please format the code. Thanks!

Comment: @Kaz, no sorry, that still doesn't answer my question. I need to call the function with just a list, not an additional function.

Comment: @RainerJoswig, Thanks for your comment, I tried my best to write the code in a more readable way.

Comment: You need to do more: readable names (not L), avoid upper case, lines should be shorter, no dangling parentheses. Indentation by two characters, space between a word and a following open parenthesis, one semicolon and not two for comments at the end of a line, only one space between expressions, ...

Comment: @Streamline The idea is that the function is still called with one list; it just uses `recursive-mapcar` instead of `mapcar`, like this: `(defun div-first (list) (recursive-mapcar (lambda (elem) (/ elem (first list))) (rest list)))`.

Comment: @Kaz `(defun divfirst (liste)
  (If (Zerop (First liste))
      'div_by_zero)
  (Labels ((div (liste d) (If (Null liste)
                              NIL
    (Cons (/ (First liste) d) (div (Rest liste) d)))))
    (div liste (First liste))))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Without proper indentation and code formatting, Lisp programming is not possible.**

Your first program properly formatted:

```
(defun divfirst (list)
  (cond ((= (first list) 0)
         (print 'div_durch_null))
        (list (/ (first (rest list))
                 (first list))
              (divfirst (cons (first l)
                              (rest l))))))
```

Your second version from the comment:

```
(defun divfirst (liste)
  (if (zerop (first liste))
      'div_by_zero)                 ; <- this if result is never used
  (labels ((div (liste d)
             (if (null liste)
                 nil
               (cons (/ (first liste) d)
                     (div (rest liste) d)))))
    (div liste (first liste))))
```

This would be a working version:

```
(defun divfirst (list &optional head)
  (if head
      (if (null list)
          nil
        (cons (/ (first list) head)
              (divfirst (rest list) head)))
    (divfirst list (first list))))

CL-USER 64 > (divfirst '(3 6 9 12))
(1 2 3 4)
```

Comment: Well it is possible, but as with any language, it's hard to read and understand by others and sometimes even yourself. Again, thank you for your comment. I'm still very new to lisp and I appreciate the advice.

Comment: @Streamline: many programming languages discourage deeply nested statements. With Lisp you write code as nested lists. Without proper indenting this gets very difficult to understand. Lisp developer ALWAYS indent their code and it's supported by the editor. So it is easy. Lisp itself also can print formatted code (see the function PPRINT for pretty print).